# IP packet fragmentation - not all fragments recieved

Tags: ipv4

What happens on a recieving device, when not all the fregments are recived?

The last fragment has the "more fragment" flag set to 1, meaning there should be another fragment after. But somewhere along the way it was discarded and lost. What does the device do ? Does it descard all the fragments before that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending upon the protocol used, the device that received the fragmented packet will either request a retransmission of the fragmented packet in its entirety (TCP) or will simply drop the packet (UDP) and not bother to continue assembling it.  What protocol are you using in this particular case?

Comment: In TCP is it still dropped and then retransmitted entirly ? or only does it leave the fragments that were succesfully trasmitted ?

Comment: In TCP, if the receiving device never sends the ACK to the transmitting device (acknowledging that it received that particular piece of the packet), and the missed segment is retransmitted and the sending device again waits for an ACK from the receiver.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if a fragment cannot be reassembled it will be dropped after some time.